# After defining the callback function, this is the outcome that I got. What am I missing out?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

```
    import os
    import tensorflow as tf
    from tensorflow import keras

# Load the data
# Get current working directory

    current_dir = os.getcwd()

# Append data/mnist.npz to the previous path to get the full path

    data_path = os.path.join(current_dir, "data/mnist.npz")

# Discard test set

    (x_train, y_train), _ = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data(path=data_path)
        
# Normalize pixel values

    x_train = x_train / 255.0
#Take a look at the shape

    data_shape = x_train.shape
    
    print(f"There are {data_shape[0]} examples with shape ({data_shape[1]}, {data_shape[2]})")

'There are 60000 examples with shape (28, 28)'

# Define callback function

    # GRADED CLASS: myCallback
    ### START CODE HERE
    def train_mnist():
    # Remember to inherit from the correct class
        class myCallback(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
            # Define the correct function signature for on_epoch_end
            def on_epoch_end(Self, epoch, logs={}):
                if ((logs.get('accuracy') is not None) and (logs.get('accuracy') > 0.99)):
                    print("\nReached 99% accuracy so cancelling training!") 
                    
                    # Stop training once the above condition is met
                    self.model.stop_training = True
    
    ### END CODE HERE

# GRADED FUNCTION: train_mnist
def train_mnist(x_train, y_train):

# Create and train your model



    ### START CODE HERE
    
    # Instantiate the callback class
    callbacks = myCallback()
    
    # Define the model
    model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
        tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation=tf.nn.relu),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax)
    ])
    
    # Compile the model
    model.compile(optimizer='adam', 
                  loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', 
                  metrics=['accuracy']) 
    
    # Fit the model for 10 epochs adding the callbacks
    # and save the training history
    history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=10, callbacks=[callbacks])
     
    ### END CODE HERE
    
    return history

# Call the train_mnist passing in the appropiate parameters to get the training history:

    hist = train_mnist(x_train, y_train)
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-1733272e84a3> in <module>
----> 1 hist = train_mnist(x_train, y_train)

<ipython-input-5-8b815e8e81b4> in train_mnist(x_train, y_train)

      5 

      6     # Instantiate the callback class

----> 7     **callbacks = myCallback()**
      8 

      9     # Define the model


NameError: name 'myCallback' is not defined
```

Answer (score 0):

You defined callback class in `def train_mnist():` function but trying to create a callback object in another function which actually doesn't have access to callback class. In simple words you're trying to do this:

```
def A():
    class B:
        pass
    
def C():
    b = B() 

C()
```

To fix this problem you need declare your callback class outside the function like this:

```
class B:
        pass
    
def C():
    b = B()
    
b = B()
```